# Getting Max Date from NSArray, KVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, key-value-coding

I've got an array of NSDates and I'd like to grab the largest NSDate from the array. While i could always sort them and grab the first/last, is there a way to do this with KeyValueCoding or some other quick one liner kind of way? I know that I could use something like valueForKeyPath@"@max.date" if the objects had a date property, but what if the objects are dates themselves??

thanks

Comment: i guess i can just use this [dateArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Comment: If you really want a one-off approach with KVC, subclass NSMutableArray and [write the operators yourself](http://bou.io/KVCCustomOperators.html).

Comment: You were on the right track except for one thing which you missed. Instead of `@"@max.date"`, you should have tried with `@"@max.self"`. I checked it myself and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use,

```
NSDate *maxDate = [dateArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

This will give you the largest date from array. You dont have to sort the array before doing this.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html),

> The @max operator compares the values of the property specified by the
>   key path to the right of the operator and returns the maximum value
>   found. The maximum value is determined using the compare: method of
>   the objects at the specified key path. The compared property objects
>   must support comparison with each other. If the value of the right
>   side of the key path is nil, it is ignored.

Note that @max will do `compare:` and then will find out the max value.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. Didn't know you could use self there. TYhanks!

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @SeanDanzeiser.  To be more specific, here's a ~70 byte one-liner:

```
// if dateArray is the array of dates ...
NSDate *maxDate = [[dateArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] lastObject];
```

Comment: This works great if you want to compare some property but need the actual item with the highest (or lowest) value, instead of the value. What's even better is to use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` and you can provide your own inline comparator. Thanks!